# it's possible deploy asp.net files in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, asp.net, deployment

It's a simple question is there a way to deploy, ASMX,C# and aspx file in apache server or other open source server. Let's say a .dll or a plugin that allows this type of files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono